# What makes this Android app debuggable

Tags: android, debugging

Until now, when I make a debuggable version of my app I use:

android:debuggable="true"

in the manifest.

But I just downloaded some source code that doesn't use this and yet when I launch it with Debug, it is in debug mode. Where is the debug flag set for this app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ADT does that for you when you run in debug mode. From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-eclipse.html):

> Ensure that your application is debuggable by setting the android:debuggable attribute of the  element to true. As of ADT 8.0, this is done by default when you build in debug mode.

Comment: So then how do I build it without Debug? Just hit Run?

Comment: @AndroidDev ok but one thind about debug is that if u want to publish your app in market then first android:debuggable="true" in manifest file.after  publish.